# Is there a way to integrate the new Google forms with an existing design?

Tags: javascript, html, google-forms

To integrate a Google form with an existing website design, I used the follow the process below :

1. Create a similar form on the target page
2. Change Action and Name values according to the ones I'd get by inspecting the Google form's source code.

I would then end up with something like this :

```html
<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/safdalfjaISv65R6J11H0o_7FadflUm/formResponse" method="post">
      <label>Name*</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name*" name="entry.895563655" required>
  
      <label>Email Address*</label>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email address*" name="entry.772189125" required>
    
      <label>Subject</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="entry.203645991">
    
      <label>Message*</label>
      <textarea rows="5" placeholder="Message*" name="entry.190021963" required></textarea>
     
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

But I tried to repeat the same process today and found myself stuck because I couldn't find the name values of the  elements anymore.

After inspecting the source code, I noticed a `jsname` attribute that wasn't unique to a given input but rather repeated for every input element and another for the inputs' label.

I'm looking for a way to integrate a Google form with my current website's design without it actually looking like one. I know that there's an API but my time and my skills are somewhat limited for now, and I'd want to get some insights from you.

The form I'm using for my test is available [here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdmO7MmcTbWFkIFkorRylauwo-MMNkDZSwGHG71M9oX1txB8w/viewform?usp=sf_link) if you want to inspect the source code. It would be too long to paste it in this post. Feel free to let me know if you think otherwise.

Thanks